# How to download multiple files from alfresco repository

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have more than 1 TB data in one site of Alfresco repository.
Now from that site i want do download all the files with .xml extension

As i checked in Alfresco share, there is no any provision provided by alfresco.

So can anyone tell me some better ways using that i can download multiple files from same site.

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Can u access the content store (the files are actually on disk, not in any kind of database)?

Comment: WebDav? Write a small script that uses CMIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Alfresco's built-in FTP server and download client like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) (supports recursive downloads and filename filters).

You can enable FTP server by settings `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties`:

```
# FTP Server Configuration
ftp.port=2121
ftp.enabled=true
```